# Как заставить телеграм бота делать вывод из БД?

Tags: sql, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть таблица sql рецептов из одной строки и двух ячеек. Подскажите, чего не хватает в коде, чтобы по команде /recipes (содержимое одной из ячеек) бот выводил
содержимое второй ячейки?

```
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher, Bot
import sqlite3
bot = Bot('token')


dp = Dispatcher()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['recipes'])
async def get_recipes(message: types.Message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('recipes.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tort")
    recipes = cursor.fetchall()

    recipes_str = "\n".join([str(recipe) for recipe in recipes])

    await message.answer(recipes_str)

    conn.close()
```